# Segmentation fault in push_back for a 2d vector

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, stdvector

I'm learning c++ and I have a problem with a segmentation fault. In my project I want to read from a File into a 2d Vector of char. 
The Vector is `std::vector<std::vector<char>> gamearea;`

```
void Structure::readFile(const std::string filename) 
{ 
    std::ifstream file(filename.c_str()); 
    if (!file.is_open()) 
    { 
       std::cerr << "Error opening file: " << filename << std::endl;    
       exit(1); 
    } 
    std::string line; 
    int i = 0; 
    while (true) 
    { 
       std::getline(file, line); 
       if (file.eof()) 
       { 
          break; 
       } 
       for (size_t j = 0; j< line.length(); j++) 
       { 
           gamearea[i].push_back(line[j]); 
       } 
       i++; 
    } 
}
```

This is my read file function and the debugger (I use gdb)  says by `push_back` is a segmentation fault.

Can someone help me? I can't find the problem.

Comment: `gameArea[i].push_back(line[j])` -- change this to `gameArea.at(i).push_back(line[j])`, and don't be surprised if you now get an `out_of_range` exception instead of a segmentation fault.  In other words, there is no`gameArea[i]` since `i` is an invalid index.

Comment: Can you explain to me why i is an invalid index and what I need to change? I want to save in the Vector the rows of a the gamearea and in other functions I need the exact position of the things in the Game like the Figure and boxes. I thought that I could say with i with row it is and with line[j] save the character in the vector so that I know the row and column of the character.

Answer (score 3):

You need to first push back into the first vector a `std::vector<char>` because by default the gamearea vector is empty, so when accessing gamearea[i] you end up accessing out of bounds (since gamearea has 0 elements inside it)

```
void Structure::readFile(const std::string filename) 
{ 
std::ifstream file(filename.c_str()); 
if (!file.is_open())  {
 std::cerr << "Error opening file: " << filename << std::endl; exit(1);
} 
std::string line; int i = 0; 
while (true) { 
    std::getline(file, line); 
    if (file.eof()) { break; } 

    // NOTICE HERE 
    // We add a new vector to the empty vector 
    std::vector<char> curArea;
    gamearea.push_back(curArea);


    for (size_t j = 0; j< line.length(); j++) {
       gamearea[i].push_back(line[j]); 
    } 
    i++;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks know there isn't a segmentation fault anymore but it doesn't save anything in the Vector. Am I forget something to save the content of the File in this Vector?

Comment: which vector isn't saved ? are you sure j is getting incremented ?

Comment: I think so. But I saw in the debugger that after std::vector<char> curArea; something like this happend `305     std::vector<char> curArea;
(gdb) step
std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >::vector (this=0x7fffffffe1a0) at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:257
257       : _Base() { }
(gdb) step
std::_Vector_base<char, std::allocator<char> >::_Vector_base (this=0x7fffffffe1a0)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:125
125       : _M_impl() { }` and I'm not sure what this tells me between the thing that it doesn't go in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of properly reading in and updating your vector, given that it is empty:

```
void Structure::readFile(const std::string filename) 
{ 
   std::ifstream file(filename.c_str()); 
   if (!file.is_open())  {
       std::cerr << "Error opening file: " << filename << std::endl; 
   return;

   std::string line; 
   while (std::getline(file, line)) 
       gamearea.push_back(std::vector<char>(line.begin(), line.end()));
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/J8iMF1)

Note we don't need to test for `eof()`.  Also, all we need to do is call `push_back` an entire string of data using the two argument std::vector constructor that takes two iterators.

Comment: Ok I think it work but I didn't get the area on my console when my show() function is called in the Main and when I go in the debugger something like this: `std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >::vector<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string>, void> (
    this=0x7fffffffe1c0, __first=35 '#', __last=0 '\000', __a=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:403
403  : _Base(__a)
` is going to happen and I don't know whats going on here. I'm not really used to understand the debugger.

Comment: See my example,  The input is read in and assigned to the gamearea 2d vector correctly.